# url rewrite for folder/base only

Tags: iis-7, web-config, url-rewriting

```
        <rule name="updates" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="updates/" ignoreCase="true" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="update.cfm" />
        </rule>
```

this works ok, except any pages under updates like `updates/signin.cfm` also redirects to update.cfm.  How do I get it to apply only when the  url ends with `updates/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL Rewrite uses RegEx in its matching expressions, so at the end of the match, make sure you delineate it to be 'the end of line'.     My Regex is rusty, but maybe its

"updates/$"  ?    Also, you might have to escape the / in the match.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html